# Trying to understand Multi dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, nested-loops

I'm trying to become a better programmer, but I'm still pretty green. I am trying desperately to better understand multidimensional arrays. This is a question from a quiz I took already, but I'm trying to practice it to get better. Here's where I'm stumped.

A modification to the encryption method from the class Cipher.java is shown below. Using the plaintext 
“123456789987654321” and keyword “NEIUP2

So, it's basically a 'put these numbers into a table' problem.

Here's a snippet of the text on which i'm stuck:

```
 // change columns according to shuffle keyword 
 for (i=6; i>0 ;i=i-1) 
 {
     for (j=0; j<5 ;j=j+1) 
     {
         newTable.setLetter(j, i-1, Table[j][5-i+1]); 
     } 
 }
```

**Given inital inputs
I    6
J   0**

For the first output I got this
J=0
i-1=5

```
**Table [j][5-6+1] = Table[0][2]**
```

So for the first line of the for loop would be

```
newTable.setLetter(0,5,Table[0][2]);
```

So what does this actually DO? If I'm looking at this in plain language the code would say,

Take the contents of Array at 0,5 and put them at position 0,2 of table. Is my logic correct?

Arrays and Nested loops are kind of hard for me to understand.

P.s. I know that this may be elementary to some of you. I am also aware there's probably better ways, or classes available. I'm really looking for fundamental understanding. Gotta walk before you can crawl right?

Comment: newTable is a new multi dimensional array. The full algorithm takes the contents of one table, and applies it to another, kind of like a copy

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) will get you more attention and better answers.

Comment: If `newTable` is an array, it can't have a `setLetter` method. I assume you've gone through the basic stuff (a.k.a. [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html))?

Comment: What's SSCCE? No, I didn't see that resource! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have `newTable[5][6]`, a 2D array

```
 int[][] newTable = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                     {6, 7, 8, 9, 8},
                     {7, 6, 5, 4, 3},
                     {2, 1, 2, 3, 4},
                     {5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
                     {8, 7, 6, 5, 4}};
```

When you loop through them,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
     }
}
```

the `5` in the outer loop causes the loop to run 5 times.  For each of those iterations, there is another loop than runs `6` times, for a total of `5 * 6` times `(30)`.

`i` and `j` in the case you wanting to use the indices in the loop, `i` and `j` represent the indices.

// e.g.
   newTable[i][j] = 1;  // i and j being the first iteration so i = 0 and j = 0

If you look at my matrix above, you will see that the top left corner, you will see the value `1`.  The `i` in `newTable[i][j] = 1;` represents `"rows"` and `j` represents `"column"`.  `rows` in this case actually go down and `columns` go accross.

So if you said

```
inx x = newTable[3][4];
```

`x` would equal `4` because you go `3` down (starting from 0) and `4` accross (atarting from 0)

Let's go back to the loop.  I may not be answering your question, but I would like to give you some insight.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        // say you have another table "table"
        table[i][j] = newTable[i][j]
    }
}
```

All the above is doing is making the value of `table[i][j] = newTable[i][j]`.  If you wanted to swap them, you could do something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        int temp = newTable[i][j];
        table[i][j] = newTable[i][j];
        newTable[i][j] = table[i][j];
    }
}
```

Like, I said, I may not be answering your question.  But one thing I want to point out is that is you were to play around with the indices, you have a good chance of getting an error message, called an `Excpetion`.  There are many different kinds of `Exceptions`.  In a case where you were playing around with the indices in the loop, there is a good chance of getting and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoudsException`.  Its exactly what it looks like.  That means, you're trying to access an `index` that is out of the `[5][6]` range.

For example if in your loop you have something like this

```
    newTable[i + 1][j] = table[i][j];
```

and the loop was in it's last iteration, which is `i = 4` and `j = 5', you would get an`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExeption`because you're trying access`newTable[5][5]` which doesn't exist.

As far as your question about this

```
newTable.setLetter(0,5,Table[0][2]);
```

I don't know what to heck that does, without seeing more code.  But your logic sounds right, given the `.setLetter()` is implemented correctly, if a `setLetter()` even exists.

Comment: set.Letter is a real Method. Here it is:

  public void setLetter(int indexI, int indexJ, char letter)
    {
     Table[indexI][indexJ] = letter;
    }

Comment: Thank you! This actually helped a lot. I guess Complex, nested loops are what's really killing me with my knowledge.

Comment: This is the teacher's reseponse. I guess this is the answer, still not sure how I could have figured this out from the loop

newTable.setLetter(0,5,Table[0][2]); 
 
is the valid values when i = 6 and j =5
 
It takes the value found in the Table [0][2] and assigns that value to NewTable[0][5]